# PDO : Insert query containing ' is not executing in SQLite3 with PHP 5.3.4 with  

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I am creating a blogging application using PHP5/SQLite3 . To insert a post in database I am executing query written below.

```
$db=connectToDatabase();
$tempcontent=$db->escapeString($tempcontent);
$query = "INSERT INTO posts VALUES (null,$temptitle, $tempcontent, $tempcategory, $tempauthor)";
$db->query($query);
$db=disconnectToDatabase();
```

I am having problem when the text input contain ' or " . when there is ', the query is not getting executed at all . If ' is not there then " is displayed with escape (\") in browser .
Sorry, I forgot to mention :
connectTodatabase() function is providing very general way to connect to database. as :

```
try {
  $db1 = new PDO("sqlite:blog.db");
}catch( PDOException $exception ){
  die($exception->getMessage());
}
return $db1;
```

Comment: You are using some custom db class. How can you expect us to know what this class is doing? But it's probably doing something wrong - just because of the fact that you are passing arguments inside the query instead of separately.

Comment: connectTodatabase() function is providing very general way to connect to database. as :
`code`
    try {
   $db1 = new PDO("sqlite:blog.db");
 }catch( PDOException $exception ){
   die($exception->getMessage());
 }
 return $db1;
`code`

Comment: `escapeString` is borked, show that (and really, favor prepared statements rather then string building/escaping).

Answer (score 0):

Just post the whole class because we are not mind readers or psychics here.

The probably problem is you are not escaping data you include in your query.

Use either mysql_real_escape_string():

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Or PDO prepared statements:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: I have not created any class . It's just a function in which I am passing $temptitle, $tempcontent, $tempcategory and $tempauthor and then using these parameters in INSERT query .